# Optimizing data Ingestion with jdbc Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, hive

I'm trying to ingest million rows tables using jdbc with spark partitioning with row number (having a cluster with 4 executors and 2 cores). The files are then written on hdfs in orc format.

But the process is really slow and I don't know how to optimize it!

Do you have any suggestion?
Since it seems that the slow part is the 'writing', would an in memory computation of the difference between the dataframes containing the new data and the old data (to reduce the number of rows to be written) kill the system or would it be helpful?

```
dataf = spark.read
          .option("numPartitions", numPartitions.toInt)
          .option("partitionColumn", "rowIndex")
          .option("lowerBound", min_val)
          .option("upperBound", max_val)
          .jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=query_table, properties=connectionProperties)
```

I tried different partition numbers (when too high, for example:
24 partitions, the process was even slower) we tried 8 partition or
16 partition with no benefits.
But the time taken is always variable, it takes 40 minutes for 120 million rows tables and then for example 8 hours for 300 million rows table and 2 days for a table with same number of rows and double the number of columns.

Comment: Mark, I just wanted to see your sql query .. if possible please share in your question ?

Comment: How did you figure out that it is the writing operation which is slow ? You can use Ganglia monitoring tool to monitor Spark resource usages and bottlenecks. I would first suggest to read the whole table into memory and materialize the read operation by `df.count()` and then time the read operation. I believe your read operation is not optimized for various reasons.

https://luminousmen.com/post/spark-tips-optimizing-jdbc-data-source-reads#set-numpartitions-wisely